# HttpClient requests universally fail unless one is created and used in the Main method of the consuming program

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, portable-class-library, socketexception

HttpClient requests within class library (.NET Standard 2.0) fail with System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An invalid argument was supplied ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An invalid argument was supplied

Unless a "throw-away" HttpClient is created, used for at least one request, and then disposed (though not really because .NET keeps a static instance) in the Main method (yes it must be the Main method) of the consuming Console App.

I have tried consuming this library via nuget package (we have an internal nuget store), by directly copying the dlls and manually installing all dependencies, and by creating a console app project within the same solution as the library and consuming using project references. All fail in identical ways. (All .NET Core 2.1)

I've tried placing the "throw-away" HttpClient and request in a separate method within the consuming program, as well as several different places within the library, including all the way up in the constructor of the main class in the library.

Here's the "throw-away" HttpClient code:

```
var testClient = new HttpClient()
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
};
await testClient.GetAsync("users");
```

I have a test suite in the library solution that uses NUnit. This test suite works perfectly. 
If I run the console app that consumes the library in any way, on Linux (even WSL Ubuntu) it works perfectly.

I can't provide an MRE as the issue is so bizarre and I can't reproduce it readily. However here are snippets in order of initialization leading to the creation of the first HttpClient in the library.

Main Class Constructor

```
    /// <summary>
    /// OCI DNS API Wrapper
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dnsSettings">DNSSettings Object, sets high level configurations for the Wrapper</param>
    /// <param name="logger">NLog Logger</param>
    public DNSAPI(DNSSettings dnsSettings, Logger logger)
    {
         Settings.ApplySettings(dnsSettings);

         APIWebClient.Init(Settings.TENANT_ID, Settings.USER_ID, Settings.FINGERPRINT, Settings.KEY_PATH, Settings.API_VERSION);
        _dnsSettings = dnsSettings;
        Settings.SetLogger(logger, _dnsSettings.LogLevel.Value);
        _errorsTable = new Dictionary<int, DnsError>();
        _keyCount = 1;
    }
```

APIWebClient Static constructor and Init method

```
static APIWebClient()
        {
            _httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                AllowAutoRedirect = true,
                PreAuthenticate = true
            })
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(Settings.BASE_ADDRESS),
            };

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }

        public static void Init(string tenancyID, string userID, string fingerprint, string pemPath, string version)
        {
            _signer = new Signer(tenancyID, userID, fingerprint, pemPath);
            _version = version;
        }
```

POST Method and Execute Request Method within APIWebClient

```
public static async Task<APIResponse> POST(string path, Dictionary<string, string> additionalHeaders, string data = "{}")
        {
            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri($"{Settings.BASE_ADDRESS}/{_version}/{path}"));

            request.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "application/json";
            request.Headers.Add("x-content-sha256",  Convert.ToBase64String(SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(bytes)));

            if (additionalHeaders != null && additionalHeaders.Count > 0)
                foreach (var pair in additionalHeaders)
                    request.Headers.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);

            using (var stream = await request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }

            request.Content.Headers.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

            return await ExecuteRequest(request);
        }
```

```
private static async Task<APIResponse> ExecuteRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            try
            {
                request.Headers.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
                request.Headers.Host = request.RequestUri.Host;

                _signer.SignRequest(request, request.Method == HttpMethod.Put);

                var webResponse = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                var apiResponse = new APIResponse()
                {
                    Body = await new StreamReader(await webResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), true).ReadToEndAsync(),
                    Headers = webResponse.Headers,
                    ResponseCode = webResponse.StatusCode
                };
                return apiResponse;
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                var webResponse = e.Response as HttpWebResponse;
                Settings.Logger.Debug($"Web Exception: {e}");
                Settings.Logger.Debug($"WebException Status: {e.Status}");
                var apiResponse = new APIResponse()
                {
                    Body = await new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), true).ReadToEndAsync(),
                    ResponseCode = webResponse.StatusCode
                };
                webResponse.Dispose();
                return apiResponse;
            }
        }
```

Sorry for the epic post. I've tried to keep it to minimal information. However, as I am unsure what relevant piece of information in this chain of events could clue us into WTF. I couldn't think of a way to shrink this post down.

EDIT: Here is the full stack trace

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An invalid argument was supplied ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An invalid argument was supplied
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at DNSAPI.Lib.APIWebClient.ExecuteRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
```

The rest of the Main method creates an instance of a test class that creates the loggeer, initializes DNSAPI and makes a single request. This is all done async.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testClient = new HttpClient()
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
            };
            await testClient.GetAsync("users");

            var wtf = new WTF();

            await wtf.Run();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

EDIT 2: After attaching MS Symbol server and manually adding break on Exception type System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException. I was taken to a Try/Catch in System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper
Looking in the Socket Event Args I found this inner exception

```
at System.Net.Dns.HostResolutionEndHelper(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Dns.EndGetHostAddresses(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.MultipleConnectAsync.DoDnsCallback(IAsyncResult result, Boolean sync)
```

EDIT 3: Here is the host I am contacting - `dns.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com`
NOTE: This host resolution somehow only fails under the above listed conditions so I am disinclined to believe that it is due to communication error or actual DNS lookup failure.

EDIT 4: I have identified the root source of the failure, though I do not yet know why this is happening. .NET Core when running on Windows uses this `NameResolutionPal.Windows.cs` from .NET Framework's `System.Net` Namespace. 
The `HostResolutionBeginHelper` method processes the host resolution request in an Async context using `AsyncCallback`. The steps of this process is handled by an `DnsResolveAsyncResult` instance. The actual request that fails is `NameResolutionPal.GetAddrInfoAsync(asyncResult)` This call fails because a prerequisite call `asyncResult.StartPostingAsyncOp(false);` is somehow being skipped. Why this is occurring I do not yet know. 
REF: https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.NameResolution/System/Net/DNS.cs,f8023b9c19212708

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace for the exception (at least until it reaches the HttpClient call you are making in your code).  Can you confirm what you are doing in the rest of your Main() function after the 'throw-away' workaround.  i.e. are all the other calls that fail being run sequentially / async / on other threads / anywhere they might have different permissions (credentials/identity/...).

Comment: Also disable 'Just my code' and run the failing version set to break on all exception.  You may get a clue from the  state / which argument is invalid.

Comment: @tolanj Updated. All async.
running without "Just my vode" now.

Comment: Stops at same location. Doesn't tell me what the invalid argument is. The native Error code is 10022 which translates to "InvalidArgument"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2

Comment: Can you confirm if you are running this on Linux / Windows / ???

Comment: Windows. 
If I run it on Ubuntu, it works fine. 
Which is extra weird as the library target is .NET Standard 2.0 and the console app target is .NET Core 2.1

Comment: I assume Settings is some sort of global static singleton, as I can't see you passing it around.  I'm interested in the fact that APIWebClient seem to have lots of static methods that refer to Settings, including in its _static_ constructor.  It seems that Settings is bootstrapped in the _class_ constructor of DNSAPI.  Put new Uri($"{Settings.BASE_ADDRESS}/{_version}/{path}") into a variable and log it.  Also you are setting BaseAddress on the HttpClient but seemingly sending full URLS, don't set base address in this case.  Could this just be a static constructor ordering issue?

Comment: Considering I have the Init method in APIWebClient, I removed the static constructor altogether. I've also dropped the BaseAddress assignment. 
Here's the result of the log (from Uri.ToString()) `https://dns.us-ashburn-1.oraclecloud.com/20180115/zones`

Correct, Settings is a global static singleton.

Comment: I created a .NET Framework Console app in the same solution as an additional test. 

Works fine. So the only path to reproduction of this issue is with a .NET Core console app consuming the wrapper and running on windows. 

change any of that and it works.